# codeigniter tank_auth unable to view default forms

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

First time posting here love the site.

So I started using CodeIgniter and wanted to add acl to my site. 
searched and read a lot and decide to go with tank auth.

using:
codeigniter 2.1.4

tank auth master

IIS

Download everything ran the scripts connected to the db and nothing...

I can't view the `register_form.php` in the view/auth folder or any view for that matter, all i get is a blank page no errors or anything. i assume its a problem with the routing i tried a 100 different stuff and was unable to get any thing beside a blank page.

any ideas how to solve this?

your help would be most appreciated.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

edit:
what have i dont so far....

1. so i change the route to this:
   $route['default_controller'] = 'auth/login';
   $route['404_override'] = '';
2. enable all logging nothing shows there
3. made sure im in develoment mode
   still nothing blank page

***edit:***

```
so sloved the problem it was with the database load ($this->ci->load->database();)
no error were showen only thing in log of CI was (Database Driver Class Initialized)
problem was that php 5.5 doesnt come enable , need to enable it.
locate the php.ini (cmd->run c:\php\php.exe --ini for location)
edit the next stuff in file:
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"

then make sure that in apachee httd.conf u have it ponted to the location of the right php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:\php\PHP.ini"

hopes this help some one in the future :)
```

Comment: Check the logs.. if necessary change log config to log everything.

Comment: just did got warning date() in log library fixed it, still nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so sloved the problem it was with the database load

```
($this->ci->load->database();)
no error were showen only thing in log of CI was (Database Driver Class Initialized)
problem was that php 5.5 doesnt come enable , need to enable it.
locate the php.ini (cmd->run c:\php\php.exe --ini for location)
edit the next stuff in file:
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"

then make sure that in apachee httd.conf u have it ponted to the location of the right php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:\php\PHP.ini"
```

hopes this help some one in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth/login'; //there is no such method in auth like you are suggesting
```

This takes you straight for log in! Make an anchor to auth/register to see register view.

Comment: did it nothing happen, still getting the blank page

Answer (score 0):

I think , there is something mistaken, I guess nobody wants to make default controller to be login. (So you got problem that you can't open auth/register or login and you want to solve it by route)

I'm using tank_auth . Never changed route settings.
Make sure that config file, library, models are there and also I suggest you to open error_reporting to get all warnings.

Open index php , at this code to line 38.

```
case 'development':
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE));
break;
```

Comment: i agree i don't want as my default login but for now its to check that it works and it doesn't.
ok so my bad should have said that i have it already config to work as development. that's why i have opened the case,

Comment: why not have first log in page? for administration for example?

Comment: im trying to use the default one that comes with tank auth the semple login page and register from there ill move on to work with my site